# Apache setup virtual hosts for multiple urls

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have the Bitnami Wampstack installed running 2 different websites, each with two different URLs. The virtual hosts are set up as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:83
NameVirtualHost www.first.co.za:83
NameVirtualHost www.first.net:83

<VirtualHost www.first.co.za:83>
  ServerName www.first.co.za:83
  DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/BitNami WAMPStack/apache2/htdocs/joomla2"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.second.net:83>
  ServerName *:83
  DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/BitNami WAMPStack/apache2/htdocs/joomla"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.second.co.za:83>
  ServerName www.second.co.za:83
  DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/BitNami WAMPStack/apache2/htdocs/joomla"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.first.net:83>
  ServerName www.first.net:83
  DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/BitNami WAMPStack/apache2/htdocs/joomla2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Three of the URLs redirect correctly, but the fourth, www.first.co.za, displays the website for www.second.net, which seems to be default. What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: @Corne. You do realise that the 3rd virtual host is pointing to the same directory as the second vhost, don't you?

Comment: Yes, that is how it should be, since hosts 2 and 3 are different URLs for the same website. The issue is with the first one, which should redirect to the joomla2 folder, but shows the joomla folder instead.

Comment: You can check how apache sees to configuration by running `apachectl -S` (apache2ctl on some os). Please attach the command's output to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only really have two sites, I'd recommend to only set up two virtual hosts and do the rest with aliases, like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:83

<VirtualHost *:83>
ServerName www.first.net
ServerAlias www.first.co.za
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/BitNami WAMPStack/apache2/htdocs/joomla2"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:83>
ServerName www.second.net
ServerAlias www.second.co.za
ServerAlias *
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/BitNami WAMPStack/apache2/htdocs/joomla"
</VirtualHost>
```

This removes the redundancies and makes for clearer reading, plus it's easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it wasn't quite correct for me. I set up the config according to your answer, but the alias for the second vhost was redirecting to the first vhost, so I added another vhost for that alias and then it worked. Thank you.